# SAS: how to use the table column with special character $

Tags: sas

I use sas manipulate some database tables. There is a column "CDR$UNPIVOT$SKEY" in one table. I can't direct use this column name in data step or Proc SQL, even i change the option of VALIDVARNAME=ANY.

Is there a way to direct use such column name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. You are very close now. All you need is to address it using its literal format.

```
option validvarname=any;
data want;
'CDR$UNPIVOT$SKEY'n = 'I can see now';
run;

proc print data=want;run;
```